# Constructing nested string with parenthesis from a list/tuple without map recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I thinking of optimizing my code by leaving out some recursive calls and replacing them by while or other iterative loops.

Recursive function is this:

```
def repr(e):
    if isinstance(e, (list, tuple)):
        return "(%s)" % " ".join(map(repr, e))
    return str(e)
```

Output for `repr([1, [2, [3, 4]]])` is `(1 (2 (3 4)))`

Is there a way to replace map-part with while loop in this case? I'd like to test the performance difference between different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `repr` already belongs to a Python built-in function, so rather than redefine it, let's assume your code is:

```
def my_repr(e):
    if isinstance(e, (list, tuple)):
        return "(%s)" % " ".join(map(my_repr, e))

    return str(e)
```

Assuming you don't want to do a simple string manipulation, but rather actually walk the list, we could replace the *implicit* recursion stack with an *explicit* stack:

```
def my_repr(e):
    stack = [e]

    result = ""

    while stack:
        item = stack.pop()

        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            stack.append(")")
            stack.extend(reversed(item))
            result += "("
        elif item == ")":
            result += item
        else:
            result += str(item) + " "

    return result
```

The above is crude, and doesn't format the string perfectly, but may be good enough for timing purposes.  The advantage over the string manipulation approach by @shotgunner is that you can do more complex things with `item` as part of adding it to the string, for example:

```
            result += str(item * item) + " "
```

Where your output string now contains the squares of the numbers in the input structure. Or whatever.

Timing-wise, you'll find that this non-recursive example is slower than your recursive one.  They're both basically doing the same amount of work, but the recursive one is doing more at the **C** level and the non-recursive one is doing more in Python.  And the non-recursive one should be redesigned not to need a call to `reversed()`.  One advantange of this non-recursive implementation is that large, complex input shouldn't trip Python's call stack limitation, like the recursive one.

Comment: Yes. For simplification I left out some code on outer return str, becauce there is extra checks on other types than lists/tuple. While with stacks looks familiar structure which I was basically looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Yet other good point on your edited reply, I forgot to mention initially. I hit sometimes the recursion limit which caused me to search for other options.

Answer (score 1):

```
def repr(e):
    return str(e).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")").replace(",", " ")
```

example:

```
>>> repr([1, [2, [3, 4]]])
'(1 (2 (3 4)))'
```

for testing the performance you can use `timeit` module like this:

```
import timeit

def repr1(e):
    if isinstance(e, (list, tuple)):
        return "(%s)" % " ".join(map(repr, e))
    return str(e)

def repr2(e):
    return str(e).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")").replace(",", " ")


duration1 = timeit.timeit('repr1([1, [2, [3, 4]]])', 'from __main__ import repr1',number=1000)
duration2 = timeit.timeit('repr2([1, [2, [3, 4]]])', 'from __main__ import repr2', number=1000)

print(duration1, duration2)
```

for bigger lists like `list(range(10000))`:

```
print(duration1, duration2)
# 1.0414706510000542 0.7595879010000317
```

you can also use `str.translate()`:

```
def repr3(e):
    table = str.maketrans("[],", "() ")
    return str(e).translate(table)
```

Comment: Good to have some options. `repr3` makes double whitespaces, which could be removed with `.replace("  ", " ")`. I was also looking for Python pprint module if it could do the job...